# PHPUnit: is it possible to strict assert equals of two arrays containing objects?

Tags: php, phpunit

I've got a two arrays of objects. I want to test if this arrays are equals, but with strict comparison, like 'false' !== 0.

Is it somehow possible with phpunit without custom comparators or so on?

Comment: Did you try to use [`assertSame`](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.1/assertions.html#assertsame) with the 2 arrays?

Comment: Yes, assertSame failed cause objects in the arrays is same by properties, but not by the links on same object.

Comment: What do the objects contain?

Comment: Well, some scalar properties, but also some other objects

Comment: It looks like [`assertObjectEquals`](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.0/assertions.html#assertobjectequals) is what you're looking for.

Comment: It cant compare array of objects :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with using symfony VarExporter:

```
self::assertSame(VarExporter::export($firstArrayOfObjects), VarExporter::export($secondArrayOfObjects));
```

Comment: By looking at the source code of this method, it may call `ltrim`, so the data may be different but some spaces will be ignored and the check will give a false positive that the data is identical.

Comment: I saw that it uses ltrim only for Enum for somewhat reasons.